# Clear startup screen in R / RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I would to change the start up/ logon screen that I get when I first open up R or actually Rstudio.  What I would like to have is just the '**>**' prompt and nothing else.

I know I have seen this on the web before but can't remember what the search phrase was.

I should have added that I am using **Ubuntu Linux**!
Any suggestions?

[image: My console in RStudio]

Comment: `r --silent` works for me thru DOS and RTerm. I imagine you can add the `--silent` bit in the start up string somewhere...

Comment: Chase's answer should work for " ... when I first open up R" ... but it seems **not** for "... or actually RStudio".  A little bit of searching the RStudio site and the Google didn't find out anything about this: I started a discussion at http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/questions/234-pass-command-line-options-to-r?unresolve=true , we'll see what happens

Comment: **--silent** does not work in Ubuntu linux :(

Comment: Read `R --help` to see the correct option name on your platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put this line to .bashrc in your home directory or .zshrc if you use zsh.

```
alias R='R -q'
```

`-q` means quiet.

Answer (score 6):

Other guys are giving you advice how to stop the messages, I will take it the other way: how to clear the console. You can press `Ctrl-L` manually. Of course, it would be nice to do this programmatically and place the appropriate command at the end of your system `.RProfile`. I tried the obvious solution:

```
cat("\014") # or cat("\f")
```

but this apparently doesn't work. You can do this:

```
cat(rep("\n", 50))
```

which will clean your console, but the cursor is at the last line. Or you may try the [solution proposed here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/clear-console-td822204.html) (I've not tested it though - please report if it works if you try it):

```
cls <- function() {
       require(rcom)
       wsh <- comCreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
       comInvoke(wsh, "SendKeys", "\014")
       invisible(wsh)
}
```

On linux console, the following could work:

```
system("clear")
```

Comment: Where is your copy of .Rprofile?  I do not have one.
system("clear") did not work, added to: ~/R/2.13/startupmsg/R

Comment: I bet `system("clear")` doesn't work from within RStudio (it doesn't on MacOS), only from command-line R.

Comment: @Ben, yes, that's sounds reasonably. oaxacamatt, I'm using Windows version so I'm not sure where's .Rprofile on linux... try home or current directory.

Comment: One can save a copy of '.Rprofile' to the /home/<user> dir in Linux and then add a simple command such as **cat(rep("\n",25))** It gets the job done but not really elegantly.

Comment: I finally tried: cls<-function()... It did not work in the .Rprofile unfortunately.

Comment: @oaxacamatt - and does it work when you run the function on console?

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
cat('\f')
```

to my .First() function in my .Rprofile works for me. I use Rstudio, (Windows 7, build 7601, Service Pack 1, x86)

Answer (score 1):

Create a .Rprofile file that contains:
'cat("\014") # Clear console`

Change "Default working directory ..." in RStudio preferences to the folder that contains .Rprofile.

Answer (score 0):

Update:   as of November 2016, this now seems to work in RStudio 1.0.44 `cat("\014")`. This is what I add to the top of my latest R scripts:

```
rm(list=ls())            # removes all objects from the environment
cat("\014")              # clears the console
```

credit to @TMS for the solution

Note: it leaves the .Last.value as NULL in the environment, but I'm OK with that

Answer (score -1):

There's a function '.First' that gets executed when you enter the console.

```
.First <- function(){
    cat("\n")
}
```

This could do it.

Comment: nope, this will just print one NEWLINE, which is not sufficient. See my post.

Comment: One can save a copy of '.Rprofile' to the /home/<user> dir in Linux and then add a simple command such as **cat(rep("\n",25))** It gets the job done but not really elegantly.