# read.table in R startup script

Tags: r, startup

**.Rprofile** (Based on [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771577/clear-startup-screen-in-r-rstudio) [2](http://www.r-bloggers.com/customizing-r-startup-script/) posts. I had to remove`.First<-function(){ }`.) :

```
cat(rep("\n", 50))
if(file.exists("~/algae/analysisTxt.r")){
    source("~/algae/analysisTxt.r")
    cat("algae was loaded")
}
```

**analysisTxt.r** :

```
algae <- read.table('http://www.liaad.up.pt/~ltorgo/DataMiningWithR/DataSets/Analysis.txt',
         header=F,
         dec='.',
         col.names=c('season','size','speed','mxPH','mnO2','Cl','NO3','NH4','oPO4','PO4','Chla','a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6','a7'),
         na.strings=c('XXXXXXX'))
```

**When run, after clearing the screen, this error shows up**:

```
Error in eval.with.vis(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  could not find function "read.table"
```

**What should I do?**

Comment: Loading a data file in your startup is a pretty weir thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read.table` is a function in `utils` package, so how about call `library(utils)` in `.Rprofile` or in `analysisTxt.r` before the call of `read.table`?

Comment: It would work. I don't know which is better. Probably either way is okay.

Comment: `utils:::read.table` is preferred I guess. Using `library(utils)` will load the package and then it may happen again later in start-up. Most R examples of this I have seen using the `:::` notation.