# Clear Views via Command in Script in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40593395/4333482), it is shown how to clear the environment with `rm(list = ls())` and clear the console with `cat("\014")` in RStudio. In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18127455/4333482), it is shown that the keystroke combination Control + Alt + Shift + W will clear all windows but the current one. How do I do something similar to the command `cat("\014")` to clear all windows but the current one, say at the beginning of a .R script? **EDIT**: I would need something that works under both Windows and (Ubuntu) Linux. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52115061/4333482) shows how to do it in (I think) Linux but the function does not work under Windows (at least, I couldn't get it to work under Windows).

Comment: I don't use RStudio, but perhaps `rstudioapi::documentClose` given input from `rstudioapi::documentId()`? (Just a guess. For anything having to do with programmatic interaction with the IDE itself, I think `rstudioapi` is a good starting point.)

Comment: I was unable to get the document ID of the Viewed table with any of the API functions: they just returned the ID of the script window. Thanks, anyways.